# SQLAlchemy and Google Cloud Sql session pool

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I am creating an async fastAPI microservice using graphql(strawberry). My database is hosted on GoogleCloudSQL and it is a postgres database. My microservice is working really good on local with local db but now when I built my connector to the GoogleCloudSQL it doesn't work that well anymore.
My question is, how can I create a session pool and yeild session to each of my requests ?

Here are some code snippets:

```
`
# [START cloud_sql_postgres_sqlalchemy_connect_connector]
import os
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncEngine
from google.cloud.sql.connector import IPTypes, create_async_connector
import asyncpg


async def connect_with_connector() -> AsyncEngine:
    instance_connection_name = os.environ["INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]  # e.g.         'project:region:instance'
    db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]  # e.g. 'my-db-user'
    db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]  # e.g. 'my-db-password'
    db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]  # e.g. 'my-database'

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC

    # initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector object
    connector = await create_async_connector()

    async def getconn() -> asyncpg.Connection:
        conn: asyncpg.Connection = await connector.connect_async(
            instance_connection_name,
            "asyncpg",
            user=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            db=db_name,
            ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC
        )

        return conn

    # The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used with SQLAlchemy
    # using the 'creator' argument to 'create_engine'

    connection = await getconn()

    pool = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg://",
        creator=connection,
        # [START_EXCLUDE]
        # Pool size is the maximum number of permanent connections to keep.
        pool_size=5,

        # Temporarily exceeds the set pool_size if no connections are available.
        max_overflow=2,

        # The total number of concurrent connections for your application will be
        # a total of pool_size and max_overflow.

        # 'pool_timeout' is the maximum number of seconds to wait when retrieving a
        # new connection from the pool. After the specified amount of time, an
        # exception will be thrown.
        pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds

        # 'pool_recycle' is the maximum number of seconds a connection can persist.
        # Connections that live longer than the specified amount of time will be
        # re-established
        pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
        # [END_EXCLUDE]
    )
    return pool`
```

And this is my session generator

```
    `@asynccontextmanager
    async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
        engine = await connect_with_connector()
        async_session = sessionmaker(
        engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
        )
        async with async_session() as session:
            yield session`
```

When I try to execute my query like this:

```
async with get_session() as session:
    selected = await session.execute(selectable)
```

I recieve this error:
"'Connection' object is not callable"

Even if when I debug I see that the `session` is of type AsyncSession

Comment: " it doesn't work that well anymore" - can you explain this in more detail please?

Comment: I receive this error when I'm trying to execute my query

`selected = await db.execute(selectable)`

"'Connection' object is not callable"

Even if when I debug I see that the session is of type AsyncSession

Comment: Can you please share the full traceback, not just the error message. "'Connection' object is not callable" doesn't mean much unless we know where that error occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling massively with this recently but found a solution on the Github repo: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8215#issuecomment-1324956281.

Since the sqlalchemy `create_async_engine` function does not support an async `creator` as of 03/02/23, you have to wrap the Google CloudSQL `Connection` object in an "asyncifying" function like so:

```py
import os
from google.cloud.sql.connector import create_async_connector
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.util import await_only

async def get_async_engine(
    db_host: str,
    db_name: str,
    db_pass: str,
    db_port: int,
    db_user: str
) -> AsyncEngine:
    connector = await create_async_connector()

    def asyncify_connection():
        from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg import (
            AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_connection,
        )
        
        connection = connector.connect_async(
            db_host,
            "asyncpg",
            db=db_name,
            password=db_pass,
            port=db_port,
            user=db_user,
        )        

        return AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_connection(
            engine.dialect.dbapi,
            await_only(connection),
            prepared_statement_cache_size=100,
        )

    return create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg://",
        echo=True,
        creator=asyncify_connection,
    )
```

This solution is rather hacky as is, but hopefully sqlalchemy can be extended soon to allow for an async `creator`.

Edit-08/03/23: Changed the code snippet as the previous code was prone to bugs due to awaiting an already awaited coroutine when the function is used concurrently.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working! I am hoping that SQLAlchemy supports an `async_creator` argument soon (I created the issue). For others seeing this in the future I hope to find a less hacky solution with the Python Connector soon and will update it here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/422